# Is there a way to block a COLLSCAN Query Planner on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I want to block any query that some user can make without filter by the property indexed. This way I'd like to prevent that MongoDB could choose a COLLSCAN as Query Planner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on `notablescan` as described here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.notablescan, this will prevent queries being executed that don't use an index. 
This is a server wide setting though and shouldn't be set on Production systems.

Comment: I've needed something that could be used in production, but your answer was good, thank you very much!